# Why is jetpack compose animateDpAsState not working?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a box, and I want to animate its width by using `animateDpAsState`.

```
Box(modifier = modifier)
{
     val animatedDpState by animateDpAsState(
     targetValue = vm.animateWidthTargetState,
     tween(3000))

     // box with animated width
     Box(
     modifier = Modifier
     .fillMaxHeight()
     .width(animatedDpState)
     .background(Color.Red))
    
}
```

In my viewModel, I have this `animateWidthTargetState`:

```
var animateWidthTargetState by mutableStateOf(0.dp)
```

And somewhere else I changed the value of `animateWidthTargetState` to that of my `screenWidth` by clicking a button:

```
vm.animateWidthTargetState = screenWidth // let's say screenWith = 360.dp
```

**The problem is** that the value of `animatedDpState` becomes `360.dp` the instant I clicked on my button, causing the width of my box to become `360.dp` instantly. It seemed that no calculation even happened and `animateDpAsState` was not working.

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: [this](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/a95dc0fc026045b2e1075a6231dcc29e) works fine to me, please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thank u for your reply.  
Now it works, but another problem has occurred. As `animatedDpState` approaches the end, the calculated values become very close, and it looks like the progress came to an end way before the time ran out.  
The calculated values are like these:  
369.03482.dp  
369.0659.dp  
369.12653.dp  
369.1852.dp  
369.24185.dp  
369.26944.dp  
369.2965.dp  
369.34915.dp  
369.39978.dp  
369.42435.dp  
369.4484.dp  
369.495.dp  
369.53955.dp  
369.56107.dp  
369.5821.dp  
369.62256.dp  
369.66104.dp

Comment: Any Composable function should be side effects free. Read more about side effects in [thinking in compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model). Animation triggers recomposition up to once a frame, and without  `LaunchedEffect` it updates the value on each recomposition, which theoretically shouldn't be a problem in this case, as the value is the same, which shouldn't trigger recomposition, but even in such cases you should use `LaunchedEffect`.

Comment: as to your second problem, I still need a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - with [mine](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/9d1f37c33a7d0092d139b2628d1bb3fa) timings are fine

Comment: Yeah, I was confused before. Now I'm going with `LaunchedEffect with keys` instead of `animateDpAsState` to fix the problem:   `LaunchedEffect(key1=somekey){delay(some time) changeKey}`.   On every recomposition, a new progress is calculated, which is then passed to a `LinearProgressIndicator`.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by change :

```
 var expanded by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }

 val animatedDpState by animateDpAsState(
    //It can be changed according to your needs
    if (expanded) 48.dp else 0.dp,
      animationSpec = spring(
            dampingRatio = Spring.DampingRatioHighBouncy,
            stiffness = Spring.StiffnessLow
        ),
 label = "")
```

and in the Box :

```
   Box(
     modifier = Modifier
     .fillMaxHeight()
     .width(animatedDpState.coerceAtLeast(0.dp))
     .background(Color.Red))
```